# strange behavior of long data type

Tags: groovy

I have problem with the `Long` data type when I run this command:

```
Long nanos = 3 * 1000000000
println nanos
```

It prints out `-1294967296`, not `3000000000`, and I dont know why.
I read on [this](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN0515-Integers) page that Long is enough. So what is wrong ?

Comment: I don't know groovy, but I'm assuming that the behaviour is similar to java - That is, the `3` and the `1000000000` are actually of type `int`, and the _calculation_ is performed in that type, before being _stored_ in a `long`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must mark your 2nd constant as long, otherwise it's considered an integer which overflows. Use:

```
Long nanos = 3 * 1000000000L
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a suffix to literals to imply that they are long values. Otherwise they are interpreted as int.

```
  Long nanos = 3 * 1000000000L;
```

More info about this [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Math).

Answer (score 4):

The arithmetic is being done with ints and then being save into a Long. Try this instead:

```
Long nanos = 3L * 1000000000L
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check this with the groovy shell (groovysh):

```
groovy:000> 3.class                 
===> class java.lang.Integer
```

The literal 3 is a `java.lang.Integer`.

```
groovy:000> (3 * 1000000000).class
===> class java.lang.Integer
```

The product of a multiplication is also a `java.lang.Integer`

```
groovy:000> 3 * 1000000000        
===> -1294967296
```

Now it's easy to see that the Integer gets converted to Long *after* the overlow happened